# What's the best way to skip CSRF for plugin controllers?

Tags: plugin-development, csrf

I'm working on a plugin that'll create a private API for content authors to post entries to Craft from desktop-based scripts. These scripts post data to plugin controller actions (anonymous-allowed), where the plugin will first check for valid Craft user account details or a plugin-generated key.

**Since I'm still enforcing authentication, what's the best way to disable CSRF checks *just for these posts* when CSRF is globally enabled?**

Thoughts I've had:

1. Attempt to put the CSRF key and token in the $_POST data as early as possible. (Probably not even possible.)
2. Have the client (desktop) script grab the CSRF key+token just before posting. (Inconvenient, potentially failure-prone.)
3. Somehow prevent CSRF protection from being enabled for requests passed to this controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Craft is piggybacking off of Yii's CSRF support for 90% of the work here and they've implemented it at the [Request](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L135) level (specifically `onBeginRequest`).

That happens way before Craft gets a chance to determine what type of request this is, much less figure out where to route it.

I think your best bet is going to be to put some logic in Craft's `general.php` config file that specifically check's for PHP's `$_GET` and `$_POST` globals for a `p=some/path/to/my/plugin/controller` and disables the [enableCsrfProtection](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#enableCsrfProtection) config setting for that request.

```php
return array(
    'enableCsrfProtection' => (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/actions/plugin/controller/action'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks Brad (and Brandon)! That'll work just fine for this particular thingamajig.

Comment: @BradBell @BrandonKelly I'm trying to do something similar, I have an action that processes Paypal IPN requests, but using `{{ actionUrl('plugin/action', {}) }}` in my template forces `$mustShowScriptName` to be set to true in `UrlHelper::_getUrl()`. This means the global `$_GET['p']` is not set, as the URL that is printed includes "index.php" like this `http://craft.dev/index.php/actions/plugin/action?param=foo`. `omitScriptNameInUrls` set to true in config seems to have no effect on this. Can you think of what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you post this as a separate new question?

Comment: @BradBell Of course, sorry about that: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/how-can-i-ensure-actionurl-from-template-does-not-show-script-name-in-the-genera

Comment: @MikePierce Actually it’s just a matter of checking `$_REQUEST['PATH_INFO']`, not `$_GET['p']`. Just updated the example code.

Comment: When you say "`config file`", do you mean put that in a plugin's config file, or do you mean in the `general.php` configuration file for Craft?

Comment: @taylor Craft's `general.php` config file. Update the answer.

Comment: If you're coming here from https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways the action routes for the payment gateway callbacks that you want to disable csrf for, according to Luke, are `actions/commerce/payments/completePayment` for all,  or `actions/commerce/payments/acceptNotification` if you use sagepay

Answer (score 23):

In Craft 3 this is a cinch:

```
class PluginController extends Controller
{
    // Disable CSRF validation for the entire controller 
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    ...
```

See the Yii2 docs for more control over inividual actions:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-best-practices.md#avoiding-csrf

Comment: This is the Craft 3 answer. Thanks, Ben!

Answer (score 11):

As [Brad's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4554/689) suggests, you can conditionally [enable or disable CSRF production](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#enableCsrfProtection) via the General Config, based on any criteria you want.

Some use cases might be:

- match a `SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` string or substring, to open up a particular set of controllers or actions
- check the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, to allow token-less requests from a particular IP or IP range
- validate 'safe' requests based on a key or encrypted timestamp from some `$_POST[]` or `$_GET[]` variable

For cleanliness, I typically try to tuck the checking/validation logic away into its own "handler" class. Then, in the `general.php`, I set the `enableCsrfProduction` item based on the result of the check...

*(In MyRequestHelper.php, something like...)*

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class MyRequestHelper
{

    public static function isApiRequest()
    {
        $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        return strpos($path, 'actions/my-api') == 1;
    }

}
```

*(In craft/config/general.php, something like...)*

```
require_once (..path/to/MyRequestHelper.php');
$isApiRequest = \Craft\MyRequestHelper::isApiRequest();

return [

    // ...other configs...

    'enableCsrfProtection' => !$isApiRequest,

];
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE: This is not necessary to do when using Commerce 2.**

---

I modified Michael's answer to add support for query strings + make it nicer to check for multiple routes:

```
if ( !function_exists('isApiRequest') ) {
    function isApiRequest ()
    {
        $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $query = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

        $actions = [
            'actions/charge/webhook/callback',
            'actions/commerce/payments/completePayment',
            'actions/some/other/action',
            'actions/commerce/webhooks/process-webhook'

    ];

    foreach ($actions as $action) {
            if ( strpos($path, $action) || strpos($query, $action) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    return false;
    }
}

return [

    // ...other configs...

    'enableCsrfProtection' => !isApiRequest(),

];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable the CSRF protection by event

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\ActionEvent;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\web\Controller;

Event::on(Controller::class, Controller::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION, function (ActionEvent $actionEvent) {
    if ($actionEvent->action->id == 'update-cart') {
        Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
});
```