# What is the best way to append CSRF token without using a form?

Tags: form, ajax, csrf

I have built a plugin that simply makes requests to a 3rd party API. I am calling my plugin action via ajax.

I don't have a form on this page currently. Here is what I am using, but I am getting the error `The CSRF token could not be verified.`

I thought I could just put a hidden input field somewhere on my template:

**twig**

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName }}" value="{{ craft.request.csrfToken }}">
```

Here is what my ajax call looks like...

**jquery**

```
var data = {
    'thing': value,
    'thing': value
};

data[window.csrfTokenName] = window.csrfTokenValue;

$.ajax({
    'type': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'cache': false,
    'data': data,
    'url': 'myplugin/doAction',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'timeout': 50000
}).done(function (response) {
    callback(response);
}).fail(function (error) {
    // Total fail.
});
```

Later on in my site I will have a form that accepts user input, so I would like to keep CSRF enabled for the entire site. Perhaps I need to ["skip" the CSRF token for these requests?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/whats-the-best-way-to-skip-csrf-for-plugin-controllers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the token and name into javascript. Easiest is to just have a script tag somewhere.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName }}";
    window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.request.csrfTokenValue }}";
</script>
```

Now they will be available to your ajax call.

Comment: Thank you! I read that on the docs, but thought... well I can see that I am setting it so whats the big deal?

I'd also like to point out to (anyone else) make sure that the above script needs to be placed above/before your ajax script is called.

Comment: If your ajax call is triggered by a user event (such as click), it can go anywhere, just append the csrf stuff to your data inside the event handler.

Comment: Ah - you are right. It looks like I must of run into a cache issue. I was getting that the csrf config did not exist otherwise. All cool now - thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

This is the syntax for Craft 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName }}";
    window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken }}";
</script>
```