# Webhook Error with Charge plugin

Tags: plugin-charge, csrf

Stripe is throwing a server error when trying to access a webhook to the Charge plugin. Some investigation revealed the error is triggered by an 'invalid or missing CSRF token.

Comment: Hey Roy... thanks for sharing.  Would you mind splitting this up into a question and adding your solution as an official answer? I bet you'll get more reputation that way. :)

Answer (score 3):

If CSRF protection is enabled (and it is by default for the latest versions of Craft), Stripe was getting a server error when using the Charge webhook url. The solution is to disable CSRF for the webhook URI - you can read more about it [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/whats-the-best-way-to-skip-csrf-for-plugin-controllers)

or simply add this to your `config/general.php` file:

```
'enableCsrfProtection' => (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/actions/charge/webhook/callback'),
```