# Request didn’t meet the user agent and IP requirement for maintaining a user session when website posts to our action URL

Tags: controller, modules

We have a module that has an action controller method that a third party website posts data to.

We can see that often, we can't save the data and there is an error "`Request didn’t meet the user agent and IP requirement for maintaining a user session`" in our web log.

I'm guessing it's this config setting "`requireUserAgentAndIpForSession`" but no idea how to turn that off for a specific request?

Comment: Try setting the value to `'requireUserAgentAndIpForSession' => (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/your/action/contoller/function')`, which would turn it off for that specific request only

Comment: That is what I have been mulling over, just wondered if there was anything that felt less hacky!

Comment: This was the official line back in 2014–https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4554/6147. I can't see any reason why it's changed, though maybe you can set it on the controller level as `public $requireUserAgentAndIpForSession = false`?

Comment: Ah ok! I hadn't seen that one. Lovely ta!!

Comment: Someone want to add that as an official answer? :P